# Display contents of json file in readable alert/console (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display contents of a json file which has 5 entries as the usual key value pairs, however I currently can only get the Name value to display as intended, the other values are registered literally as a direct return of the in put code. The `getJSON` method is to start after a button with id of `#json` is clicked. Its working but only displays the first item with the rest being output literally.
The code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#json', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var items;
    $.getJSON('somedata.json', function(data) {
      items = data;
      console.log(items['Name'], ['Phone'], ['Mphone'], ['Email'], ['Message']);
    });
  });
});
```

Tips welcome ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not pulling the other values from `items` as with the first, do this instead:

```
console.log(items['Name'], items['Phone'], items['Mphone'], items['Email'], items['Message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add items before ['Phone'], ['Mphone'] etc..

```
console.log(items['Name'],items['Phone'], etc..)
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it displaying to console log, however I would also like to know how to display it in an alert using sweetalert, any tips welcome !